# What is a suitable way to analyse my data? [actual data uploaded]

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, dataset, mean, fishers-exact-test

Two species of bird winter at my study site. Lets call them "Dark Species" and "Light Species".

Dark Species and Light Species are spatially segregated: Dark Species tends to be found on the eastern side and Light Species tends to be found on the western side.

This segregation is readily apparent in the field but a reviewer has asked me to demonstrate this segregation statistically.

I counted Dark Species and Light Species on the western side and also counted Dark Species and Light Species on the eastern side. My data are below:

```
   side       species count
1  west  Dark Species     0
2  west  Dark Species     0
3  west  Dark Species     0
4  west  Dark Species     0
5  west  Dark Species    20
6  west  Dark Species     0
7  west  Dark Species     0
8  west  Dark Species     0
9  west  Dark Species     0
10 west  Dark Species     0
11 west Light Species     0
12 west Light Species    10
13 west Light Species   100
14 west Light Species   530
15 west Light Species   720
16 west Light Species   600
17 west Light Species     0
18 west Light Species     0
19 west Light Species     0
20 west Light Species     0
21 east  Dark Species     0
22 east  Dark Species     0
23 east  Dark Species     0
24 east  Dark Species     0
25 east  Dark Species     8
26 east  Dark Species    90
27 east  Dark Species   280
28 east  Dark Species   100
29 east  Dark Species    10
30 east  Dark Species     0
31 east  Dark Species     0
32 east  Dark Species     0
33 east  Dark Species     0
34 east Light Species     0
35 east Light Species     0
36 east Light Species     0
37 east Light Species     0
38 east Light Species     0
39 east Light Species     3
40 east Light Species    20
41 east Light Species     0
42 east Light Species     0
43 east Light Species     0
44 east Light Species     0
45 east Light Species     0
46 east Light Species     0
```

And R code for my data:

```
structure(list(side = c("west", "west", "west", "west", "west", 
"west", "west", "west", "west", "west", "west", "west", "west", 
"west", "west", "west", "west", "west", "west", "west", "east", 
"east", "east", "east", "east", "east", "east", "east", "east", 
"east", "east", "east", "east", "east", "east", "east", "east", 
"east", "east", "east", "east", "east", "east", "east", "east", 
"east"), species = c("Dark Species", "Dark Species", "Dark Species", 
"Dark Species", "Dark Species", "Dark Species", "Dark Species", 
"Dark Species", "Dark Species", "Dark Species", "Light Species", 
"Light Species", "Light Species", "Light Species", "Light Species", 
"Light Species", "Light Species", "Light Species", "Light Species", 
"Light Species", "Dark Species", "Dark Species", "Dark Species", 
"Dark Species", "Dark Species", "Dark Species", "Dark Species", 
"Dark Species", "Dark Species", "Dark Species", "Dark Species", 
"Dark Species", "Dark Species", "Light Species", "Light Species", 
"Light Species", "Light Species", "Light Species", "Light Species", 
"Light Species", "Light Species", "Light Species", "Light Species", 
"Light Species", "Light Species", "Light Species"), count = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 20, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 100, 530, 720, 600, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 90, 280, 100, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 3, 20, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-46L), .Names = c("side", "species", "count"))
```

Using my raw data above, how can I demonstrate statistically that Dark Species tends to be found on the eastern side and Light Species tends to be found on the western side? Note that the data contain a lot of zeros, which are causing issues.

Note that when I say "demonstrate statistically", I'm looking for a significance test and P-value.

One thing I've tried is calculating the mean value for Dark Species and Light Species on the western and eastern sides, then running a Fisher's Exact Test on the resultant 2 x2 contingency table. However, I am told that a Fisher's Exact Test doesn't make sense if the values in the contingency table are mean values.

Comment: For a [contingency table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingency_table) you would typically sum the counts, rather than averaging them.

Comment: Do the specific rows matter? East/west seems to be the grouping of interest, so is there a reason that you are not working with sums for those groups (as mentioned by GeoMatt22)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be easiest to convert the data.frame to a case-by-case table format:

```r
install.packages("DescTools")
library(DescTools)

# having created a data.frame named 'data.birds' using the provided structure
data.birds <- Untable(data.birds, freq = "count") 

> head(data.birds)
  side      species
1 west Dark Species
2 west Dark Species
3 west Dark Species
4 west Dark Species
5 west Dark Species
6 west Dark Species

# lets see how the data is structured
> xtabs(~ side + species, data = data.birds)
      species
side   Dark Species Light Species
  east          488            23
  west           20          1960
```

source: [Tables in R: A quick practical overview](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DescTools/vignettes/TablesInR.pdf)

Now, lest test this:

Performing a simple $\chi^2$ test:

```r
> summary(xtabs(~ side + species, data = data.birds))
Call: xtabs(formula = ~side + species, data = data.birds_x)
Number of cases in table: 2491 
Number of factors: 2 
Test for independence of all factors:
    Chisq = 2233.8, df = 1, p-value = 0
```

Performing Fisher's test (which is mostly used on smaller data):

```r
> fisher.test(matrix(c(488,20,23,1960), c(2,2)))

    Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  matrix(c(488, 20, 23, 1960), c(2, 2))
p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 1122.192 4300.262
sample estimates:
odds ratio 
   1954.62
```

For a concise, yet surprisingly robust summary of different frequency tests see [this from the R-Cookbook](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Statistical_analysis/Frequency_tests/).